# How to Track events of Email like Open, reply and click on laravel 9

Tags: php, laravel, email

I am building an campaign site where I need to track different types of events after sending an email. Like it is opened or not, clicked or not, or replied or not. I tried many ways to implement it but failed. I already tried by pixel image but it didn't work. Can anyone help me with that. Ow how does mailchimp or sendinblue(brevo) works. I need to know the mechanism.

Comment: like click on a button from the email? just open the email? and reply that email to another email?